# How to create a rounded window in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

How to create a rounded window in Ubuntu?
Lang: C++

For [example](http://addons.miranda-im.org/files/screenshot/48-1-1247311190-tipperym.jpg) like the [tipper plugin](http://addons.miranda-im.org/details.php?action=viewfile&id=3717) from Miranda.

Comment: Did you try to download the source code of tipper plugin and see how it works? I downloaded and executed grep command (grep -i -R round *). There are many code snippets that you can find a example how to round the window

Comment: This might just be my opinion, but sticking with the standard way your Window Manager draws window borders might be preferred by some users. It's usually a usability plus if all windows have a consistent design/layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about jagged edges (no anti-aliasing), you can just use the [XShape](http://www.xfree86.org/current/XShapeSelectInput.3.html) (aka "X11 Nonrectangular Window Shape") extension: this lets you define a "mask" that cuts down the area of your window.  Anything outside of this mask, even if it falls within the rectangular area of your window, is see-through and pass-through to the windows below.

If you have a compositing window manager running (`xcompmgr`, Compiz, etc.) you can additionally create your window as 32-bit ARGB, and use the alpha to blend the edges away.  (To avoid confusion, this should be done together with XShape.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [cairo](http://cairographics.org/OpenGL/) and OpenGL to create a transparent window.

Comment: Do you know any example how to use it for create rounded / transparent window?
Thanks

Comment: Just render a rounded rectangle.